# Nova Pivot BelongsToMany not working in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova

I have the following Pivot table:

```php
public function sheeps()
{
    return $this
       ->belongsToMany(Sheep::class, 'farm_sheep')
       ->withTimestamps()
       ->withPivot(['weight', 'foobar']);
}
```

Now I want a `BelongsToMany` field that shows the values that are in the pivot Table, so: *weight* and *foobar*.
But when I do that, it just shows the table with the data from the Sheep Nova resource. So not that pivot tables values. What am I doing wrong

```php
BelongsToMany::make('Sheeps')
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
            Number::make('Weight'),
            Textarea::make('Foobar'),
        ];
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define those fields in both ends of the relationship. From the Nova [docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/relationships.html#belongstomany):

> Once these fields are attached to the relationship field, and the relationship has been defined on both sides, they will be displayed on the related resource index.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? @Kenny Horna

Comment: We can't tell because you only posted the info of one resource in the direction to the `Sheep` one. How about the other way? (from the `Sheep` model/resource to the other one)

Answer (score 0):

Even having defined both sides of the relationship, I was not able to get this to function as intended.  What worked for me was adding a pivot field to the original resource's `fields()` output:

```php
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            Text::make('Type'),
            Boolean::make('Premium', 'pivot.premium'),
        ];
    }
```